# GeoServer: points' symbols with a WKT polygon geometry?

Tags: geoserver, sld, well-known-text

I need to define custom points symbols in a SLD file for GeoServer. It seems that some WKT strings are accepted and others are not. I need to draw a closed line with a fill color.

The following example is accepted (symbols are displayed) but I can't specifiy a fill because it is just a linestring :

```
<WellKnownName>wkt://MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 0 1), (0 1, 1 1), (1 1, 1 0), (1 0, 0 0))</WellKnownName>
```

I have tried the followings to be able to fill the shape:

```
<WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON(0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)</WellKnownName>
<WellKnownName>wkt://MULTIPOLYGON(0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)</WellKnownName>
```

The symbols are not displayed and I don't know how to debug it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for both polygon and multipolygon, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Geometric_objects

Try:

```
<WellKnownName>wkt://POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))</WellKnownName>
<WellKnownName>wkt://MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)))</WellKnownName>
```

Comment: Many thanks! I had not noticed the double bracket... Not so intuitive.